# Haskell http-conduit

Tags: haskell

Im using http-conduit to get a web page.

```
import Network.Connection (TLSSettings (..))
import Network.HTTP.Conduit

main :: IO ()
main = do
    request <- parseUrl "https://somesites.com"
    let settings = mkManagerSettings (TLSSettingsSimple True False False) Nothing
    res <- withManagerSettings settings $ httpLbs request
    print res
```

I get this message

```
statusMessage = "BadClient"
```

and i couldn't see the response body

What is wrong here?
I'm guessing that the server doesn't like non-browser access.
Is there anyway i can masquerade as a firefox browser for example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You certainly simply need to add a User-Agent Header.

```
simpleHTTPWithUserAgent :: String -> IO ()
simpleHTTPWithUserAgent url = do
    r  <- parseUrl url
    let request = r {requestHeaders = [("User-Agent","HTTP-Conduit")]}
    let settings = mkManagerSettings (TLSSettingsSimple True False False) Nothing
    res <- withManagerSettings settings $ httpLbs request
    print res
```

You might replace "HTTP-Conduit" by a Firefox one.